# Drag&Drop in JTable with JLists as tablecells

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jtable, jlist

I want to move around my tasks from the JTree to the JLists in the JTable
and also move them from one JList to another. (see image)
The results look good so far, but I have the problem that the cursor "flicker" if I want to move a task to a tablecell if this is not in "edit mode".
So, when I first select the cell, and the cell is then in "edit mode" it's ok, but if I want to move a task from the tree to a cell which isn't selected before or move a task from one table row to another your cursor "flicker" again.

So, has anyone an idea why the cursor "flicker"?

[gui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L01Si.png)

Here is my code:

```
public class JListTableMain
{
    JListTableModel tm = new JListTableModel();
    JTable table = new JTable(tm);
    DefaultTreeModel model = new DefaultTreeModel(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("root"));
    JTree tree = new JTree(model);

    public JListTableMain()
    {
        tm.testData();
        table.setTransferHandler(new TableTransferHandler());
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellRenderer(new JScrollTableRenderer());
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellEditor(new JScrollTableEditor());
        table.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e)
            {
                table.setRowHeight(16);
                Dimension p = table.getPreferredSize();
                int tableHeight = table.getHeight();
                int perRow = tableHeight / table.getRowCount();
                table.setRowHeight(perRow);
            }
        });
        JPanel pMain = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(10, 10));
        pMain.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        tree.setDragEnabled(true);
        tree.setDropMode(DropMode.ON);
        tree.setTransferHandler(new TreeTransferhandler());
        this.initTree();
        pMain.add(new JScrollPane(tree), BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        pMain.add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.getContentPane().add(pMain);
        f.setSize(750, 500);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void initTree()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            ((DefaultMutableTreeNode) model.getRoot()).add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new TaskObj(i, "task " + i)));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
        }
        catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException | ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new JListTableMain();
            }
        });
    }

    public class TaskObj extends Object
    {
        private String todo;
        private int number;

        public TaskObj(int number, String todo)
        {
            super();
            this.todo = todo;
            this.number = number;
        }

        public String getTodo()
        {
            return todo;
        }

        public void setTodo(String todo)
        {
            this.todo = todo;
        }

        public int getNumber()
        {
            return number;
        }

        public void setNumber(int number)
        {
            this.number = number;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return number + ": " + todo;
        }
    }

    public class JListTableObject
    {
        private String name;
        private ArrayList<TaskObj> tasks = new ArrayList<TaskObj>();

        public JListTableObject(String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
            for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++)
            {
                tasks.add(new TaskObj(i, "task"));
            }
        }

        public String getName()
        {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public ArrayList<TaskObj> getTasks()
        {
            return tasks;
        }
    }

    public class JListTableModel extends AbstractTableModel
    {
        private final List<JListTableObject> entries = new ArrayList<JListTableObject>();

        public void addJListTableObject(JListTableObject entry)
        {
            entries.add(entry);
            this.fireTableDataChanged();
        }

        public void removeJListTableObject(int index)
        {
            entries.remove(index);
            this.fireTableDataChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount()
        {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount()
        {
            return entries.size();
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int columnIndex)
        {
            switch (columnIndex)
            {
                case 0:
                    return "Name";
                case 1:
                    return "tasks";
                default:
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong column");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
        {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
        {
            JListTableObject entry = entries.get(rowIndex);
            DefaultListModel<TaskObj> listModel = new DefaultListModel<TaskObj>();
            switch (columnIndex)
            {
                case 0:
                    return entry.getName();
                case 1:
                    return entry.getTasks();
                default:
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong column");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
        {
            JListTableObject entry = entries.get(rowIndex);
            switch (columnIndex)
            {
                case 0:
                    return;
                case 1:
                    return;
                default:
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong column");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex)
        {
            switch (columnIndex)
            {
                case 0:
                    return String.class;
                case 1:
                    return ArrayList.class;
                default:
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong column");
            }
        }

        public void clear()
        {
            int size = entries.size();
            entries.clear();
            this.fireTableDataChanged();
        }

        public List<JListTableObject> getJListTableObjectEntries()
        {
            return entries;
        }

        public JListTableObject getJListTableObjectEntry(int index)
        {
            return entries.get(index);
        }

        public void testData()
        {
            entries.add(new JListTableObject("User1"));
            entries.add(new JListTableObject("User2"));
        }
    }

    abstract class TaskTransferHandler extends TransferHandler
    {
        DataFlavor dataFlavor;

        protected abstract TaskTransferable exportData(JComponent c);

        protected abstract void processData(TransferSupport support);

        protected abstract void cleanup(JComponent c, boolean remove);

        public TaskTransferHandler()
        {
            try
            {
                dataFlavor = new DataFlavor(DataFlavor.javaJVMLocalObjectMimeType + ";class=\"" + TaskObj.class.getName() + "\"");
            }
            catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Transferable createTransferable(JComponent c)
        {
            return exportData(c);
        }

        @Override
        public int getSourceActions(JComponent c)
        {
            return COPY_OR_MOVE;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean importData(TransferSupport support)
        {
            if (canImport(support))
            {
                processData(support);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        protected void exportDone(JComponent c, Transferable data, int action)
        {
            cleanup(c, action == MOVE);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean canImport(TransferSupport support)
        {
            if (support.getComponent() instanceof JTable)
            {
                JTable.DropLocation dl = (JTable.DropLocation) support.getDropLocation();
                if (dl.getColumn() == 0)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            for (DataFlavor flavor : support.getDataFlavors())
            {
                if (dataFlavor.equals(flavor))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    class ListTransferHandler extends TaskTransferHandler
    {
        @Override
        protected TaskTransferable exportData(JComponent c)
        {
            System.out.println("@List: create transferable");
            JList list = (JList) c;
            return new TaskTransferable((TaskObj) list.getSelectedValue(), dataFlavor);
        }

        @Override
        protected void processData(TransferSupport support)
        {
            System.out.println("@List: processData");
        }

        @Override
        protected void cleanup(JComponent c, boolean remove)
        {
            System.out.println("@List: cleanup");
        }
    }

    class TreeTransferhandler extends TaskTransferHandler
    {
        @Override
        protected TaskTransferable exportData(JComponent c)
        {
            System.out.println("@Tree: createTransferable");
            JTree tree = (JTree) c;
            TreePath path = tree.getSelectionPath();
            if (path == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            DefaultMutableTreeNode firstNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) path.getLastPathComponent();
            return new TaskTransferable((TaskObj) firstNode.getUserObject(), dataFlavor);
        }

        @Override
        protected void processData(TransferSupport support)
        {
            System.out.println("@Tree: processData");
        }

        @Override
        protected void cleanup(JComponent c, boolean remove)
        {
            System.out.println("@Tree: cleanup");
        }
    }

    class TableTransferHandler extends TaskTransferHandler
    {
        @Override
        protected TaskTransferable exportData(JComponent c)
        {
            System.out.println("@Table: createTransferable");
            JTable table = (JTable) c;
            int row = table.getSelectedRow();
            int col = table.getSelectedColumn();
            Object val = table.getValueAt(row, col);
            return new TaskTransferable((TaskObj) val, dataFlavor);
        }

        @Override
        protected void processData(TransferSupport support)
        {
            System.out.println("@Table: processData");
        }

        @Override
        protected void cleanup(JComponent c, boolean remove)
        {
            System.out.println("@Table: cleanup");
        }
    }

    public class TaskTransferable implements Transferable
    {
        TaskObj data;
        DataFlavor dataFlavor;
        DataFlavor[] flavors = new DataFlavor[1];

        public TaskTransferable(TaskObj data, DataFlavor dataFlavor)
        {
            this.dataFlavor = dataFlavor;
            flavors[0] = dataFlavor;
            this.data = data;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getTransferData(DataFlavor flavor) throws UnsupportedFlavorException
        {
            if (!isDataFlavorSupported(flavor))
            {
                throw new UnsupportedFlavorException(flavor);
            }
            return data;
        }

        @Override
        public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors()
        {
            DataFlavor[] dataFlavors = new DataFlavor[1];
            dataFlavors[0] = dataFlavor;
            return dataFlavors;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor flavor)
        {
            return dataFlavor.equals(flavor);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return "DataTransferable [data=" + data + "]";
        }
    }

    public class JScrollTableRenderer implements TableCellRenderer
    {
        DefaultListModel<TaskObj> listModel = new DefaultListModel<TaskObj>();
        JList<TaskObj> list = new JList<TaskObj>(listModel);
        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(list);

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
        {
            listModel.removeAllElements();
            listModel.addAll((Collection) value);
            return pane;
        }
    }

    public class JScrollTableEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor
    {
        DefaultListModel<TaskObj> listModel = new DefaultListModel<TaskObj>();
        JList<TaskObj> list = new JList<TaskObj>(listModel);
        ListTransferHandler handler = new ListTransferHandler();
        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(list);

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int rowIndex, int vColIndex)
        {
            list.setDragEnabled(true);
            list.setTransferHandler(handler);
            listModel.removeAllElements();
            listModel.addAll((Collection) value);
            return pane;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getCellEditorValue()
        {
            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The "flicker" is due to the fact that the `JTable` cell is being constantly repainted as long as the mouse is being dragged. This may help. [Showing the Drop Location](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/showdroploc.html)

Comment: So, but I want to have the visual feedback if it can be dropped or not, so it's a problem i cannot solve?